# Laravel ajax pagination printing out entire site

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination

On my site's user pages, there's a section called "Reviews". In reviews, as you can imagine, there's a list of reviews for that user.

In the controller:

```
$reviews = Review::where('artist_id', $user->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(5);
```

in the markup:

```
@if ($reviews->count())
<div class="artistContain">
    <h3>Reviews</h3>
    <div class="reviews endless-pagination" data-next-page="{{ $reviews->nextPageUrl() }}">
        @foreach ($reviews as $review)
        <div class="review">
            {{ $review->body }}
        </div>  
        @endforeach
        <div class="pagerHolder">{!! $reviews->render() !!}</div>
    </div>
</div>      
@endif
```

Cool. It lists 5 reviews, then you have to click the pagination button which will refresh the page and show the next set of reviews.

However, I don't want users to have to refresh the page, so I'm trying out ajax.

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(url, function(data){
        $('.reviews').html(data);
    });

});
```

Now this works. Kinda. Problem is, it'll inject the ENTIRE NEW PAGE into the reviews div. But hey, at least it brings up the right results.

How would I fix this so that the `.html()` method ONLY brings me the next set of results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to load page fragments and avoid loading the entire page

```
// container is the id of the returned reviews container
// Change it to your returned review container id
$( ".reviews" ).load( url +" #container" );
```

Comment: Nice answer. (as compared to my answer) :). @linktoahref good job

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by doing following steps;

**In Controller**

```
$reviews = Review::where('artist_id', $user->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(5);

if(request()->ajax())
{
    return $reviews;    // in case of ajax, return only data instead of view
}
else
{
    return view('name-of-your-view', ['reviews' => $reviews])
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(url, function(data){

        $('.reviews').empty();                  // make it empty first

        $.each(data, function(i, review){
            $('.reviews').append('<div class="review">'+review.body+'</div>');
        });

    });

});
```

**Explanation**

Controller: We need to modify the controller that when request is ajax then it will return only $reviews collection instead of complete view.

JavaScript: When data is recieved, we will first empty the $('.reviews') div and then append new reviews divs.

**Note**

Above code may have syntax error because I did not type it on Code Editor and I also did not test it. But this is the correct method to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What am I supposed to put in "'+review.body+'"?

Comment: @FelixMaxime You don't need to put anything. it is coming from $.each(data, function(i, review){..., just copy paste above code and your problem solved :)